# Site only loading with 'www' domain prefix

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system

My site is only loading with www.domain.com format not with domain.com. Any idea why? Here are my settings:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin getintouch@domain.com
 ServerName domain.com
 ServerAlias domain.com www.domain.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public_html/
 ErrorLog /var/www/domain.com/logs/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

My DNS settings:

A/AAAA Records

```
 Hostname   IP Address          TTL 

            123.123.123.123     Default 
 www        123.123.123.123     Default
```

Running Ubuntu on Apache2

Comment: You do not need to list domain.com in ServerAlias if it's already the ServerName. Other than that the config *looks* fine. What error do you get? Can you post the output of `wget htto://domain.com` and `wget http://www.domain.com`? Or, even better, reveal the domain name?

Comment: @zhenech When I type both in my browser domain.com is going to /var/www/ but www.domain.com is going to /var/www/domain.com/public_html/ for some reason. So they both work, just are directing traffic to the wrong folder.

Comment: You define `DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public_html/`, so `/var/www/domain.com/public_html/` is the correct folder and *should* work for both. Is this the only `<VirtualHost>` you have defined?

Comment: @zhenech This isn't the only one. I just made another one. I suppose things stopped working after I made that one. The other one is a subdomain of domain.com. It is the only `<VirtualHost>` in this file though.

Comment: What are the ServerName and ServerAlias lines of the other VirtualHost? Apache does not care if the hosts are in one or multiple files.

Comment: `ServerName trafficcontrol.domain.com`
     `ServerAlias trafficcontrol.domain.com`

Comment: The complete file of the other VirtualHost http://pastebin.com/38f4pk9m

Comment: As said, no need to double the same name, but that's not a problem. Any other files defining virtualhosts? What does a `grep -r domain.com /etc/apache2/` yield? Does Apache warn about overlapping virtualhosts when starting?

Comment: @AlexMarkov What's the output from `apachectl -S`?

Comment: @ShaneMadden http://pastebin.com/1jzAJEt9 it looks like domain.com is linked to the default for some reason. Do you think that it was is causing it?

Comment: @zhenech Here are the results: http://pastebin.com/MKy6pTtZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vhost to load first gets precedence - in this case, it's the one in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`.  I'm assuming that the vhost you're intending to be active is the one in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain.com`, right?

Run `a2dissite default`, then restart Apache and you should be good!

Comment: This worked! Question: where is the vhost loading sequence defined? Default may be useful, is there a way to just put it last in order? Also, how some www.domain.com went before domain.com even though it was in the same `<VirtualHost>` ?

Comment: @AlexMarkov It's in load order - when a directory is included, then it's alphabetical, which is why the "default" file that comes in the package gets that `000` stuck in front of it.  Now that you've disabled it, your `domain.com` file now acts as the default for hostnames that don't match one of the other virtual hosts.  I'm guessing the reason that `www.domain.com` went to the right vhost is that it was not configured as a `ServerAlias` in the `default` file, so the `default` file wasn't overriding that name, just `domain.com`.

Comment: But the default host should never have matched in the first place, as it does not contain `domain.com` anywhere?

Comment: @zhenech Based on that `apachectl -S` output provided in the comments on the question, the vhost in the `000-default` file had a `ServerName` of `domain.com` - so you were right on with the overlapping vhosts.